# Explicit Login/logout custom user from DB with IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

I am using scheme with authentication using my DB and ASP Core identity Server. I also implemented `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` and `IProfileService`.
I am connecting to server through `tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync` method and dont use MVC

Everything seems working as expected, but I want to set IsLoggedIn property to my user and save it in DB and when session will be over, set it to false.

What is the best place to do it? Didn't find answer anywhere.

**EDIT**

Additionally I want to mention that i use IdentityModel client lib to connect to IdentityServer, so I have no rest api in my case

Comment: This seems a simple question but is rather broad. When is in your definition a user logged in? And what session are you refering to? Are you using IdentityServer4 with JWT tokens or reference tokens?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I think user is logged in, when all auth procedures committed successfully, but I don`t know how to catch that moment exactly. That is my question about. Actually I want to have only one sign in session per user and not allow to have multiple signins until user is sign out explicitly or by timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a token is requested, the Token Endpoint is called. You can use the ProfileService to hook into the flow. You can add your own version:

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
        var principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);

        var claims = principal.Claims.Where(claim => context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains(claim.Type)).ToList();

        // Add your code ...

        context.IssuedClaims = claims;
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
        context.IsActive = user != null;
    }
}
```

Please note the `context.Caller`. This indicates the used endpoint. For an access token and refresh token this should be `ProfileDataCallers.ClaimsProviderAccessToken`.

Don't forget to register the service:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    ...
    .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

---

But the Token endpoint isn't called always. In case you login to IdentityServer directly, you'll need to add code to the `login` method. When you are using the sample projects of IdentityServer then you'll have an AccountController in the IdentityServer project. Add your code in the `login` method after this line:

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.Id, user.UserName, props);
```

In the same way you can change the status in the logout method.

---

This only confirms when a user needs a new access token, but not if the user is actually logged in after that. Most users probably never logout and most likely the cookie will be destroyed or simply expires.

So you may want to consider to set the access token to a short lifetime, like 5 minutes and consider a user logged out after 5 minutes. As the access token is expired, the user needs to login again (or refresh the access token).

---

You can limit refresh tokens to one time use only. You can also consider to use [Reference tokens](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html) instead:

> When using reference tokens - IdentityServer will store the contents
>   of the token in a data store and will only issue a unique identifier
>   for this token back to the client.

If I'm not mistaken you can limit this to one active token.

Comment: So, when `GetProfileDataAsync` is called, it means that user already logged in to the server? 
Also where can I find example with reference tokens using DB (EF Core)? Maybe there is some example using ASP Identity + IdentityServer4?

Comment: Yes, an access token is required to acces the UserInfo endpoint. You can use the sample from https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage. Set the token type: `client.AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference;` and add a secret to the API, as described here: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/reference_tokens.html